# Why File System Watcher is almost blind?

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher, file-rename, batch-rename

I am using FileSystemWatcher in order renaming files within a Watched directory.

The problem occurs if the number of files copied **simultaneously** to the watched directory exceeds the number of 50...

The rename event is fired successfully for the first 50 files, but after that nothing happens

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to give it a bigger InternalBufferSize.  And repond quickly to change events.  Queuing them, then processing the notification in another thread is best.  That also helps you deal with the inevitable locked file problems.